# javascript forEach scope

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have the following code

```
    var tempGameState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.gameState))
    tempGameState.forEach(function(row.bind(this), rowNum){
       ...
    }));
```

when I put my console.log before the forEach loop like so:

```
    var tempGameState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.gameState))
    console.log(this.gameState)
    tempGameState.forEach(function(row.bind(this), rowNum){
       ...
    }));
```

I get my game state as the output

but when I put it inside the forEach loop like so:

```
    var tempGameState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.gameState))
    tempGameState.forEach(function(row.bind(this), rowNum){
        console.log(this.gameState)
       ...
    }));
```

I get `undefined`.

I know this (ususally) has to do with scoping, but  [the javascript docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) don't say anything about a new scope being created or how to handle this.

Comment: wait, what?  you can't use `row.bind(this)` as an argument name; how does this run at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation **you linked to** states

> If a thisArg parameter is provided to forEach(), it will be passed to callback when invoked, for use as its this value.  Otherwise, the value `undefined` will be passed for use as its this value. The `this` value ultimately observable by callback is determined according to the usual rules for determining the this seen by a function.

So, to get what you want

```
tempGameState.forEach(function(...){
   ...
}, this))
 ^^^^^^
```

Comment: the provided solution worked for me.  I'm still not 100% sure why though.  Doesn't the callback default to the previous state? (or the process from which called the method in the first place)

Comment: _Doesn't the callback default to the previous state?_ without a `thisArg` **The this value ultimately observable by callback is determined according to the usual rules for determining the this seen by a function.** - the rules being - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Thanks for the link.. I understand so much more about javascript now.